# Apply some functions to the column of dataframes in the list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, lapply

I know we can use apply or lapply to do what for loop can do in R. If you have a dataframe you can just use `apply (dataframe,2,mean)` to calculate the mean of the columns however what if we have list of dataframes and I need to make following adjustment by removing the first column and convert the dataframe to numeric.
lets say the list of dataframe is LIST where LIST[[1]] is the first dataframe.

How to use lapply on list of dataframes to perform the above operation at once. How can I do operation on a dataframe inside list using lapply since

```
lapply(LIST, function (x) some function)
```

apply the operation to list not to the dataframe. and following is not making any sense:

```
lapply(LIST[], function (x) some function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the `list`, subset the columns of the dataset by removing the first column, loop through that subset, convert to `numeric`, assign the output to the dataset, and return that dataset

```
lapply(LIST, function(x) {x[-1] <- lapply(x[-1], as.numeric); x[-1]})
```

or another option is

```
lapply(LIST, function(x) data.frame(lapply(x[-1], as.numeric)))
```

Also, if it needs to be converted based on type, an easier option is `type.convert` which can be applied on `data.frame`s

```
lapply(LIST, type.convert)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(LIST, ~ .x %>%
               transmute_at(-1, as.numeric))
```

Comment: Can you explain what {x[-1] <- lapply(x[-1], as.numeric); x}  does ? I assume lapply(x[-1], as.numeric); remove the first column and convert dataframe to numeric but what does {x[-1] <- lapply(x[-1], as.numeric); x} the whole thing do?

Comment: @user59419  It is to update the data.frame in the list.  If you only use `lapply(x[-1], as.numeric)` it returns a `list` of numeric vectors

Comment: This did not work after I used  LIST2=lapply(LIST, function(x) {x[-1] <- lapply(x[-1], as.numeric); x}). LIST2 still has the first column of LIST and still looks like it is not numeric array

Comment: @user59419  Because I didn't remove the first column.  You need `x[-1]` as return

Comment: @user59419  Please see the update.  I am assuming that you have a `list` of `data.frame` and note that there was no reeproducible example

Comment: Yes thank you so much and yes I had list of dataframes.

Comment: btw this does not convert the data frame to numeric matrix. to make it to work I had to use data.matrix on every dataframe

Comment: @user59419  Yes, you can use `data.matrix`